# Allow connection to gmail account in a python script

Tags: python, email, smtp, gmail

I am trying to send an email using a python script like so:

```
import smtplib, ssl

port = 465  
smtp_server = "smtp.gmail.com"
sender_email = "my@gmail.com" 
receiver_email = "receiver@gmail.com" 
password = "123456"
message = """\
Subject: Hi there
This message is sent from Python."""

context = ssl.create_default_context()
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_server, port, context=context) as server:
    server.login(sender_email, password)
    server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message)
```

but unfortunately, Gmail blocks this connection, after running this code I receive an email saying that someone tried to access my account from an app that is not owned by Google, does anyone know a solution to this problem?

Comment: Did you do ```starttls()```

Comment: i tried doing that but i get an error: "STARTTLS extension not supported by server"

Comment: Are you sure you set all the security settings in Gmail and your Google Account correctly? Also, before calling `server.login`, try doing this: `server.ehlo()`